# How to create a Modal in react triggered without button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to create a model in react material UI library which shows the info on the landing page as the user logs in.
I have tried triggering with timeout but im unable to close the modal once it appears.

```
const[post,setPost] = useState('')
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
const handleClose = () => {
setOpen(false);
};

useEffect(() =>{
setTimeout(()=>{
setNotesPopup(true);
},3000);
},[]);

const Popup=((props) =>{
return(props.trigger)
    
})

return (
<>
  <NavigationBar/>
  <SydBackdrop openBackdrop={openBackdrop} />
  <Container maxWidth="xl" className="mb-2">
    <Card className={classes.card}>
      <CardHeader title="Customer Search Parameters" className={classes.cardHeader}/>
      <CardContent>


        <Dialog trigger={notesPopup} setTrigger={setNotesPopup} aria-labelledby="customized-dialog-title" open={open}>
                <DialogTitle id="customized-dialog-title"> UI changes</DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent dividers><Typography gutterBottom><Markdown>{post}</Markdown></Typography></DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                <Button autoFocus onClick={handleClose} color="primary">OK</Button>
                </DialogActions>
                </Dialog>

                </>
                )
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a global state that is available to your entire app like Redux or React's context api.

Put a property that has `modalStatus` as false. When the user logs in, update that value in your global state to true and when the user closes the modal, it sets it to false